# iPhone Cache Manager

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a reusable Cache Manager component which can be plugged into other iPhone projects. My cache manager should support caching of Screens(with data in them) as well as images. The primary idea would be to reduce network activity.

I am comparatively new to iPhone and have some basic iPhone programming knowledge. Please let me know of the following-

1. Am I thinking in the right direction?

2. Does iPhone architecture supports this kind of caching? If so, how?

3. Also, any pointers towards related iPhone code samples or URLs?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: @jano can you pls share what are the generic cache implementations for images and other objects in iphone and what design patterns can we use here? thanks

Comment: I use a modified version of https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared written by Marcus Zarra and others. It's not a lot of code but it may be hard to understand if you are a beginner, in which case, you shouldn't worry about network access at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to roll your own solution but I'll recommend a project on Github to get you started with the code. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) has some great code for using the cache. 
You are going to be dealing with the NSFileManager a lot. Specifically check out SDImageCache.m